# Swift: iOS Facebook version compiler errors

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I recently update the fb pods.

I am using 4.25.0 where i am getting complier errors in

```
extension LinkShareContent: SDKBridgedContent {
  internal var sdkSharingContentRepresentation: FBSDKSharingContent {
    let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentDescription = self.description // ERROR
    content.contentTitle = self.title // ERROR
    content.imageURL = self.imageURL // ERROR
    content.quote = self.quote
    content.contentURL = self.url
    content.hashtag = self.hashtag?.sdkHashtagRepresentation
    content.peopleIDs = self.taggedPeopleIds
    content.placeID = self.placeId
    content.ref = self.referer
    return content
  }
}
```

Please suggest me which version of facebook should use to avoid these compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using `FBSDKSharingContent` comment below 3 lines as this is FacebookSDK issue.

```
content.contentDescription = self.description
content.contentTitle = self.title
content.imageURL = self.imageURL
```

Comment: It worked for me but why can't facebook fix this issue.

Comment: this might fix in next version.

Comment: Hi, if this or any other answer helps you to solve your problem kindly accept answer this will helps other to identify correct answer.